# Show process status in Web App

Tags: java, shell, process

My web application is running on WAS. Web application starts another Java program through Shell Script. I am using ProcessBuilder class to execute the Shell Script.

Now I have a requirement to identify whether Java process that was started by Shell Script is still running or not. Since web application is stateless so when the user closes the browser or app session and comes back to the application, the application should show whether the process is still running or not.

Please suggest how can we get the process status in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

Let the process store the status in a persistence destination such as Database or file, then use it to display the status in web application.

Comment: There is a possibility of  process to be crashed or completed. Even if I have a handler how would I know if process is still running or not.